# Como posso pegar a data do BD já formatada usando as funções Max e Date_Format Juntas

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando buscar a maior data cadastrada em meu `BD`, estou tentando usar as funções MAX e DATE_FORMAT juntas e o resultado da pesquisa não é o esperado, tenho essas datas cadastradas:

```
2016-10-24
2016-10-25
2016-10-26
2016-10-27
2016-10-28
2016-10-31
2016-11-01
2016-11-03
2016-11-04
2016-11-07
2016-11-08
```

O que a consulta me retorna é o dia `2016-10-31` e deveria ser `2016-11-08`, entendo que não estou executando a consulta de forma correta, o que estou fazendo no momento é isso:

```
SELECT MAX(DATE_FORMAT(Data,'%d/%m/%Y')) as DataInicial FROM calendarioDolar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve primeiro encontrar a data usando o `MAX` e só após isso formatar, senão o banco de dados entenderá que deve procurar usando a ordem alfabética. Corrigindo a posição teriamos:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(Data),'%d/%m/%Y') as DataInicial
  FROM calendarioDolar
```

Comment: Olá @Sorack, muito obrigado pela dica, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Disponha! Vou adicionar uma breve explicação. Se você puder aprovar como resposta correta será que de grande valia para quem pesquisar pelo mesmo problema

Comment: Estou aguardando os 4 min para aprovação, tem um limite de tempo entre a resposta e a aprovação.