# Ajuda com data na impressão do pedido

Tags: php, mysql, sql-select

Tenho um campo na tabela que está  definido como `dtConcat2` `timestamp` `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` e no inserte ele pega a data do servidor e grava nesse campo, o problema quando vou imprimir a fatura o campo data sai assim: ***Data do Pedido:*** `03 10:32:49/12/2017`

Meu código está assim:

```
<strong>Data do Pedido:</strong>
<?php      
        echo implode('/',array_reverse(explode('-',$detalhe['dtConcat2'])));
?>
```

a hora fica no meio entre o dia e o mês, como corrijo isso para imprimir a data corretamente?

Comment: Deu certo alguma resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que no seu campo o formato é data e hora, então primeiro é extrair a data e depois com a data formatar a saída como quiser, exemplo:

```
<strong>Data do Pedido:</strong>
<?php      
   $data_hora = explode(' ',$detalhe['dtConcat2']);
   echo implode('/',array_reverse(explode('-', $data_hora[0])))." ".$data_hora[1];
?>
```

existe uma forma que é com [date_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query) formatando a saída da sua data direto na `SQL` do banco `MySQL` exemplo:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(dtConcat2, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as dtConcat2Formatada FROM table;
```

eu por exemplo, prefiro formatar a saída na `SQL`.

***Referencias***

- [MySQL DATE_FORMAT Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/)
- [date_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637581/mysql-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-select-query)
- [Como posso pegar a data do BD já formatada usando as funções Max e Date_Format Juntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164193/como-posso-pegar-a-data-do-bd-j%C3%A1-formatada-usando-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-max-e-date-format-j)
- [Data no formato dd/mm/yyyy?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29586/data-no-formato-dd-mm-yyyy/29588#29588)

Comment: Porque eu fui agraciado com -1? alguém pode explicar para que eu possa arrumar? tem algum problema a minha resposta?

Comment: amigo, ele não deixa mudar, ele só abre -1 e -2, como eu arrumo?

Answer (score -1):

Voce explode a hora antes, pelo espaço...

```
$data = explode(" ", $detalhe['dtConcat2']);
echo implode('/',array_reverse(explode('-',$data[0])))." ".$data[1];
```